# Global keyword in nested functions of Python

Tags: python, global-variables, nested-function

Following is a function with a nested function. Please help me understand why value of 'x' is same before and after calling bar(). And why x=25 when we call the main function.

```
def foo():
    x = 20

    def bar():
        global x
        x = 25

    print("Before calling bar: ", x)
    print("Calling bar now")
    bar()
    print("After calling bar: ", x)

foo()
print("x in main: ", x)
```

This is the output we get:

```
Before calling bar: 20
Calling bar now
After calling bar: 20
x in main: 25
```

Shouldn't the code print out x=25 after calling bar() since it has x as global variable?

Answer (score 1):

`global` is used to access global namespace outside of a local context, so in your example you access the namespace outside of `foo`. That's why the value of `x` inside `foo` is unchanged. If you want to access values inside `foo` from `bar`, you have to use `nonlocal` instead. This will result in a `NameError` when you try to print `x` on the last line of your script, since `x` is no longer defined in your global namespace:

```
def foo():
    x = 20

    def bar():
        nonlocal x
        x = 25

    print("Before calling bar: ", x)
    print("Calling bar now")
    bar()
    print("After calling bar: ", x)

foo()
print("x in main: ", x)  # Raises NameError because x is not defined in global namespace
```